# count tasklist ruby processes and say if count has changed (or is less than another number) in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to count the ruby processes running every 30 seconds and if the count changed, alert me with  "OH NO!" preferably.  Thanks everyone!

but I can't even get this to work...not equal to 50

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('tasklist ^|find /I /C "ruby.exe"')do set count=%%G

IF "%%G"=="50" ECHO OH NO!

timeout /t 10
```

Comment: The `FOR` meta-variable only works within the scope of the `FOR` command. I gave you the code the set a variable named `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attempted to set the count variable, but though it was still wrong, you never tried to use it, so let's set it correctly and actually use the count:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "ruby.exe"') do set count=%%a
if "%count%" equ "50" echo Oh No.
timeout /t 10
```

To match the previous variable, let's just save variable 1, run the check again after 30 seconds and compare the 2 variables in a loop.

```
@echo off
:start
set count=
set count2=
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "ruby.exe"') do set count=%%a
timeout /t 30
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "ruby.exe"') do set count2=%%i
if "%count%" equ "%count2%" (
  cls
  echo Count the same
  goto :start
   ) else (
   cls
   echo Current count %count2% has changed from %count%
   pause
)
```

Comment: Ooops, I see the variables were set up all wrong, also equ.  Thank you.  I'll give you a point when I'm I have more feedback.  works perfectly.